# What should be the polarities of the op amp input terminals such that the system is stable?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, transfer-function, feedback, stability

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHJGjZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ignore the - and + signs on the opamp (I couldn't erase it using the schematic), is it possible to determine the polarity of the op amp input terminals, using just the information of the resistors in this circuit, such that the **System is stable**?

By stability I am referring to a state where it doesn't oscillate.

Comment: This circuit is incomplete, left sides of R1 and R3 are floating (?) so it is unclear how this circuit operates.

Comment: Also: when using an **ideal** opamp such a circuit is always stable, you might get an infinite output voltage but it will **never oscillate**. For practical opamps it **can** oscillate but that does not solely depend on the feedback network. Ergo: you have a lot to learn about opamp circuits. Look for: "Opamps for everyone" and study it.

Comment: As FM hints, your 'stable' can mean two things: will it not staurate (are the + and - inputs connect in the right way), or will it not oscillate. These are totally different questions. The first is much easier.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Bruce Carter?

Comment: I was actually referring to the Ron Mancini one. be safe, read both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I assume using the term "stable" you intend to use such a circuit for linear amplifying purposes, correct? I further assume that the left nodes of R1 and R3 will be connected to common ground (as defined by the not shown double voltage supply) or to a voltage source.

Then, if the used opamp is universal-compensated (most opamps are) the circuit will operate in the linear region if the negative feedback overrides the positive feedback. For the resistor values as shown in your diagram this will be the case for the shown polarity of the opamps input terminals. The negative feedback factor is k(-)=0.5 and the positive feedback factor is k(+)=100/300=0.333.

There are three different alternative operational modes: Non-inverting gain (R1 grounded), inverting gain (R3 grounded), differential gain (R1 and R3 connected to voltage sources).

Comment: How do you find the negative and positive feedback factor? This was what I had intended to ask, but didn't know how to?

(N.B Your assumptions are all correct, I've edited the schematic to make it more clear)

Comment: I think, the definitions for both feedback factors are quite logical:k(-)=R1/(R1+R2) and k(+)=R3/(R3+R4). For the given values we have k(-)=0.5>k(+)=0.333. Hence, the negative feedback loop dominates. This is necessary for dynamic stability.

Comment: So is it V<sub>f</sub> divided by V<sub>out</sub> ?

Comment: I cannot verify your expressions. The feedback factor is the output voltage portion which arrives at the corresponding opamp terminal (voltage divider rule) when all input signal sources are set to zero.